# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el número de la semana dentro de un Mes con un JDateChooser?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un `JDateChooser` y necesito saber lo siguiente:
Cuando oprima una fecha, quisiera saber exactamente si el día elegido pertenece a la semana 1, semana 2, semana 3, etc del mes. Solo he podido obtener el Día, Mes y Año del mes seleccionado.

He investigado por otros lados y aun no doy con la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más fácil es utilizando la clase Calendar, lo que tienes que hacer es obtener la fecha del JDateChooser y asignarlo en la Clase Calendar:

```
    Date date = jDateChooser.getDate(); // Obtenemos la fecha del jDateChooser

    Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance(); // Inicializamos Calendar con la fecha y hora actual
    // y asignamos la variable date Date al Calendar de esta forma
    calendario.setTime(date);

    // Esta es una lista de lo que puede obtener con calendar según la fecha
    System.out.println("Año: " + calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println("Mes: " + calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    System.out.println("Día: " + calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    System.out.println("Día de la Semana: " + calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    System.out.println("Día del Año: " + calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    System.out.println("Semana del Año: " + calendario.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
    System.out.println("Semana del Mes: " + calendario.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)); // Esta es la que necesitas
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesitaba, le agradezco mucho, bendiciones!!